# Batch Command to populate json text file

Tags: json, batch-file

wondering if it possible for a batch command to go into a json file and set values. For example, Json File

```
        { "JsonSample" : [{
          "Field1": %Value From Batch Command%,
          "Field2": %Value From Batch Command%
        }]}
```

Comment: Sure might just not be the most productive method tough. Do you want to create the file or just replace some lines?

Comment: I am trying to change some value like change the value of field1

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
SET var1=Value1
SET var2=Value2

xidel.exe -s -e "{'JsonSample':array{{'Field1':'%var1%','Field2':'%var2%'}}}"
{
  "JsonSample": [
    {
      "Field1": "Value1",
      "Field2": "Value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

To save that as a json, simply redirect to a file:

```
xidel.exe -s -e "{'JsonSample':array{{'Field1':'%var1%','Field2':'%var2%'}}}" > output.json
```

(Use `array{` `}` for Xidel 0.9.9 and later. Use `[` `]` for Xidel 0.9.8 and older)